# Gulp.js. Same task on watch, with different parallel tasks

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I use gulp 4.0. And I have, this `'watch'` task:

```
gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", gulp.series("sass")).on("unlink", function(filepath) {
        remember.forget("sass", path.resolve(filepath));
        delete cached.caches.sass[path.resolve(filepath)];
    });
    gulp.watch("templates/**/*.jade", gulp.series("jade")).on("unlink", function(filepath) {
        remember.forget("jade", path.resolve(filepath));
        delete cached.caches.jade[path.resolve(filepath)];
    });
});
```

So, I have same two lines:

```
remember.forget("jade", path.resolve(filepath));
delete cached.caches.jade[path.resolve(filepath)];
```

If it was a pipelines, it would be easy to create new task, and then run them. But here, I have a argument (parameter) - `filepath`.

So, the question is: How i can replace it with one task? With no repeat of these two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is: How i can replace it with one task?

You can't. Tasks cannot take arguments. Your only option is to create a function:

```
function runTask(taskName) {
  return function(evt, filepath) {
    if (evt === "unlink") {
      remember.forget(taskName, path.resolve(filepath));
      delete cached.caches[taskName][path.resolve(filepath)];
    }
    gulp.series(taskName)();
  };
}

gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("scss/*.scss").on("all", runTask("sass"));
  gulp.watch("templates/**/*.jade").on("all", runTask("jade"));
});
```

Note that the above code presumes that you want to clear the `sass` and `jade` caches before running the `sass` and `jade` tasks. If it's the other way around you'll have to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need, but what about this: https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/hmdkbm7k

Why, this isn't run my tasks?

Comment: It does run your tasks. But only when you delete a file, because you've registered your function only for the `unlink` event.

Comment: It' doesn't because when i have event `all`, filename is defined. But when I leave event to `unlink`, `filename` is not defined. do you know where is a problem?

Comment: I ran the code you posted. `filepath` is defined when using the `unlink` event. If that's not the case for you maybe try filing an issue with [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar).